# Exploding Kittens- Slap to get out of multiple turns

Tags: exploding-kittens

What I’m trying to find out is:

- If you get slapped (let’s say triple),
- And you play something in-between (you don’t currently have a slap in your hand),
  e.g. an alter the future and put another slap on top,

Can you now play that slap to push the rest of your turns on to another player?
(now that the alter is between it no longer adds onto the previous slap).

Does that negate both your remaining turns and push the complete slap onto your chosen opponent? or
Do you remove one of those for the 3rd turn? or
Can you not do it at all?

Answer (score 2):

You have been slapped thrice, so you now have 3 turns to complete.
If you have a slap card as return, you can shift all to another player. But if you don't have a slap card, you can not return.

But if you draw a slap card in an other turn, you can transfer all the remaining turns to another player. see [The rules](https://explodingkittens.com/downloads/rules/Exploding_Kittens_Party_Pack_Edition_Rules.pdf).

> **Double slap**
>
> End your turn without drawing a card and force any other  player to
> take 2 turns in a row. This is not the same as drawing 2 cards in a
> row! The target of this card should take their first turn (play cards
> and/or draw). When their turn is over, it’s their turn again. If the
> targeted player plays a Slap Card in return, they pick a player to
> take ALL remaining turns (4 turns, then 6, and  so on). Play always
> continues from the targeted player. If you draw and defuse an
> Exploding Kitten during a series  of turns, you must continue taking
> your remaining turns.

**Example**
You are targetted with a tripple slap and you have no slap to return. So you are forced to take the turn(s).

- Turn 1, you draw a slap. You now have 2 turns to complete.
- Turn 2, you play the slap. You target another player that gets the 2 turns of the card + your remaining turns (2nd and 3rd) for a total of 4.