# Exploding kittens. How many turns can an attack card "really" skip?

Tags: exploding-kittens

Scenario:
P1 plays attack 
P2 plays attack. 
P3 has 4 turns on her.
P3 plays a turn and draws a card.
P3 has 3 turns left. 
P3 plays her attack. 

What happens? [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exploding Kittens- Slap to get out of multiple turns](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39531/exploding-kittens-slap-to-get-out-of-multiple-turns)

Comment: @ken 'slap cards' are only there in the party pack. This is the original edition I'm referring to. Thanks for the comment none the less :) appreciate it

Comment: Given that slap cards are just a targeted version of an attack, I would say they work exactly the same regardless of the name.

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate. It is close but it is different enough for a separate question.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe despite the difference of name of the card talked about, both questions are essentially the same - if you have to take multiple turns due to a Slap/Attack, can you take one or more turns normally, then play a Slap/Attack to shift the rest of your turns to another player. The answer is "yes" regardless of which card we are talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here.
ThankYou Ken and Toon for the replies. :)

---

#### How many turns can an attack card “really” skip???

It can skip all the turns that you have piled up on you. +  it will make the next player take any remaining turns plus 2 more.

#### Scenario:

P1 plays attack 
P2 plays attack. 
P3 has 4 turns on her.
P3 plays a turn and draws a card.
P3 has 3 turns left. 
P3 plays her attack.

What happens?

P3 gets to skip her remaining 3 turns, they are transferred to P4.
P4 so has to play 3 + 2 (P3's attack) = 5 turns in total. 
(P4 has to play only 2 turns - if playing acc to the nerfed version of the attack card)

---

The rules talk about the existence of a THE NERFED VERSION, where The remaining turns are not carried over to the next player. Its for the players to decide before game how they want to play.

[image: Official Rules]

Comment: Note that the nerfed version was the original version, despite what the name implies.