# Exploding kittens - playing cards between attacks

Tags: exploding-kittens

Related, but not a dupe: [Exploding kittens. How many turns can an attack card "really" skip?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44306/exploding-kittens-how-many-turns-can-an-attack-card-really-skip)

That questions discusses this scenario:

1. Player A plays Attack.
2. Player B takes a turn, draws an Attack and plays it.
3. Player C has to take three turns.

That is clear. But in this scenario:

1. Player A plays Attack.
2. Player B plays some other cards (Favour, See the Future or whatever).
3. Player B plays Attack (so does not draw a card).

Does Player C now have to take four turns or three? Or should Player B have played the Attack as his first card?

An argument for Player C taking four turns is that Player B could have done exactly the same thing whilst not being under the influence of Player A’s Attack and force Player C to take two turns, so they are just stacking those two into the two from the first Attack. However, I felt that by playing cards, Player B was essentially taking a turn which should be completed by drawing a card. He could then play the Attack as his second go and force Player C to take three turns.

Comment: @JoeW someone with a VTC itchy trigger finger? Too many if those on SE these days. I have referenced this very question in the first line of my question and explicitly pointed out how they are different.

Comment: I fail to see why your question is not answered in the linked question. Just because you claim it is not a duplicate does not mean that it isn't one in the eyes of someone else. The simple fact is that playing a single or multiple cards are treated the exact same way for the purpose of a turn so both scenarios you listed are treated in the exact same way.

Comment: The difference is the effect of the extra cards (which is none) but it still is a slightly different question than the one referenced.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Since there is no difference in the answer it can be correctly answer by the question that was mentioned as a duplicate.

Comment: @JoeW Two different questions that have the same answer are not, at least on other Stacks I frequent more, considered duplicates. In really simple terms, how many maths problems can have the solution “2”, answer; probably infinite. That does not make them all the same.

Comment: Everyone I have been on have leaned towards it being a duplicate if the answer is the same for both questions and the question is about the same overall subject which in this case is the same game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A player is allowed to play any number of cards in any order from their hand during their turn before drawing (as long as those cards don't end their turn in a different way, such as a Skip), so Player B certainly can play other cards before an Attack card.

From [the rules](https://www.explodingkittens.com/downloads/rules/Exploding_Kittens_Rules.pdf) (page 1 under **Taking Your Turn** step 1):

> After you follow the instructions on the card, you can play more cards. You can play as many cards as you’d like.

There are no rules anywhere that state an Attack card must be played first.

Player C would then have to take 4 turns.

Again from the rules (page 2 under **Attack**):

> Immediately end your turn(s) without drawing and force the next player to take 2 turns in a row. The victim of this card takes a turn as normal (pass or play then draw). Then, when their first turn is over, it’s their turn again. (If the victim of an Attack Card plays an Attack Card, their turns are immediately over, and the next player must takeany remaining turns plus 2 more; e.g. 4 turns, then 6, and so on.)

Player B does not actually end their first turn, so Player C takes Player B's two remaining turns plus two more from the Attack.

Comment: This makes sense and was the same argument made to me during the game so I’m coming round to this way of thinking. +1.

Answer (score 2):

The other cards do not end the turn so they have no effect on the number of turns played.

1. Player A has 1 turn to play.
2. Player A plays Attack.

   - This ends the turn of player A
   - And it forces player B to take 2 turns.
3. Player B has 2 turns to complete.
4. Player B plays some other cards (Favour, See the Future or whatever).

   - This has no effect on the turn because the turn only ends with a draw.
5. Player B has still 2 turns to complete.
6. Player B plays Attack

   - This ends the (first) turn of player B.
   - It forces player C to take 2 turns.
   - Because player B has one turn left, this turn moves to player C.
7. Player C has 2 + 1 = 3 turns to complete.

See also [the rules](https://explodingkittens.com/downloads/rules/Exploding_Kittens_Rules.pdf).

Comment: Wait, everything about your answer up to the final conclusion sounds like you are saying Player C should take 4 turns, but then you end it saying they should take 3. If at step 2 Player B has not ended a turn, then there are still 2 turns to take plus the two added by B’s Attack card.

Comment: Which, minus the extra cards played by B, is exactly the scenario laid out in the rules where the number of turns to be taken increments in 2’s.