# Nope card following a chain of Attack Cards

Tags: exploding-kittens

In a game of Exploding Kittens, what happens when a chain of attack cards is terminated by a Nope card?

For example;

- Player A plays an Attack card
- Player B plays an Attack card
- Player C plays an Attack card
- Player D plays a Nope card

What happens exactly?

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you have two questions, please post them as two separate posts rather than combining them like this.

Comment: But what i wanted to do at that moment was to place nope card not as my turn but so as would any person do so that i would nope players C attack card but not as in my turn/ i was. Really meant to ask this so does something change then?

Answer (score 10):

Player D nopes the attack card of player C. So it is still player C's turn and he/she has to resolve the double attack.

[See this question for the resolution of the double attack.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44306/exploding-kittens-how-many-turns-can-an-attack-card-really-skip)

Comment: But what i wanted to do at that moment was to place nope card not as my turn but so as would any person do so that i would nope players C attack card but not as in my turn/ i was. Really meant to ask this so does something change then?

Comment: You play the Nope as a reaction to the Attack. So the Attack did not happen.

Comment: The rules posted in the linked answer suggest that player C would be taking 4 turns in "full" rules and 2 turns in "nerfed" rules. I don't know enough about the game to say which rules are the real/current ones. Could you update this answer to clarify, so we do get exactly what happens?

Comment: @Jontia, Covered by my answer

Answer (score 7):

Nope cards aren't played on your own turn.

> You can play a Nope card at any time before an action has begun, even if it’s not your turn

You play them as a reaction to the card whose effect you want to nullify before it takes effect.

> Stop any action except for an Exploding Kitten or a Defuse card.

The scenario:

1. Player A plays an Attack card.

   1. The Attack cards takes effect (ending their turn and giving Player B two turns).
2. Player B plays an Attack card.

   1. The Attack cards takes effect (ending their turns and giving Player C four turns).
3. Player C plays an Attack card.

   1. Player D plays a Nope card.

      1. The Nope card takes effect (canceling the Attack card)

Because the Attack card had no effect, it's still Player C's turn. In fact, Player C has three other turns after this one (because of Player A's and Player B's attacks).

---

Note the original ("nerfed version" of the) rules did not have chained Attacks carry forth extra turns, so C would only have one extra turn rather than three.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario:

Player A plays an Attack card.
The Attack cards takes effect (ending their turn, meaning they don’t have to draw card from pile, and giving Player B two turns).
Player B plays an Attack card, as the first of their two turns, ending that turn without having to draw a card. Their remaining turns, which would be one, plus two turns, pass to Player C. Player C now has to take 3 turns.
Player C plays an Attack card, as the first of their 3 turns, which immediately ends that turn, meaning they don’t draw a card, and passes their remaining 2 turns, plus two new turns, to Player D.

Player D plays a Nope card.
The Nope card takes effect (canceling the Attack card which Player C played for the first of their 3 turns. Player C now has to play 2 more turns.