# Exploding kittens defuse card

Tags: exploding-kittens

We're playing 2 player exploding kittens. We had 4 attack cards in a row yielding 8 turns for player B. There is only 1 card left in the draw pile , which is the exploding kitten. When player B draws the exploding kitten and plays their defuse card, the rules state their turn is over. Should we take turn to mean a single turn? In other words does player B still need to draw 7 more times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We had 4 attack cards in a row yielding 8 turns for player B.

For the nerfed version: The attack card does not stack in Exploding Kittens. It is not like the +1 in Uno (if you get the reference).

If you play an attack on me, I have to draw 2 cards. If I play an attack card on top of your attack card, my turns are immediately over and you have to play two turns.

For the current version, player B has to play 8 turns.

> Should we take turn to mean a single turn?

Yes, a single turn, but player B has to play 2 turns (nerfed version) or 8 turns (current version).

So if I understood correctly,

- player B played attack on A
- player A played attack on B
- player B played attack on A
- player A played attack on B
- player B has to play two turns or eight depending on the version you're playing. So B has to draw the last card on the deck, which is an exploding kitten. Player B draws the exploding kitten, plays a defuse and has to put the exploding kitten back on the deck. Since there is only one card left player B puts the exploding kitten back on the draw pile facing down.
- Player B finishes her first turn.
- It is player B turn again. Player B must draw a card from the deck which is an exploding kitten.

In your case, player B had an extra defuse? If not, player B explodes and loses the game. If player B had an extra defuse card, it can draw the EK, play its defuse, put EK back in the draw pile and it is player A's turn.

If you are playing the current version, player B won't have 8 defuse cards. So player B loses the game.

I hope that helps

Comment: I am playing the version where they do stack (I believe originally they did not). See this answer. https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/44309/2694

Comment: oh I see... yeah I guess I played the older version... ill update the answer

Comment: does it make sense now? Thanks for showing me that rule, I didn't know ;-)